# I have VBA excel 2003 using some arabic language text, it's working very good, but

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA excel 2003 using some arabic language text, it's working very good on most computers with defferent version of OS and different MS-offices, but when I use it on some PC's had same properties of others it shown as unknown language!! any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

finaly I found the answer after trying several theories, I found the problem in updating the office.

so if any one have same issue just update your office and it works